# favicon.ico 503 text/html

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7, favicon

favicon.ico 503 .netcore iis.
Only 1 place that references favicon and its in _Layout.cshtml.
In this file it has type of image but the error in browser says the favicon type is text/html.

Why is this happenning.
Nothing in my code references the location of favicon shown in the browser error.

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/adding-favicons-to-your-asp-net-core-website-with-realfavicongenerator/

Comment: Turns out it was a netscalar issue.

Comment: then post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a browser thing. Each time a browser visits a site it looks for that file to put an icon in your tab, and in any bookmarks. Your code doesn't have to refer to it anywhere.